# How to make framework in CocoaPods that has multiple targets?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, carthage, swift-package-manager

I write a framework and I like to divide framework to small separate submodules (targets). Apple provides a cool description for thing I want to achieve with CocoaPods:

> Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
>   Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.

I could easily do it with Swift Package Manager:

```swift
    targets: [
        .target(name: "Network"),
        .target(name: "Service", dependencies: ["Network"])
    ],
```

I could use `import Network` in a `Service` target and it's cool because they are separate modules, logic is clear.

**How to achieve it in CocoaPods and Carthage (I write a framework, not the final application)?**

### What I've tried:

#### Subspec

I tried to use [subspecs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec):

```rb
  s.subspec 'Service' do |ss|
    ss.dependency 'MyFramework/Network'
    ss.source_files = 'Sources/Service/**/*.swift'
  end

  s.subspec 'Network' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = 'Sources/Network/**/*.swift'
  end
```

It doesn't work as I want because CocoaPods just merges all files into one framework (just divides it to separate folders), so:

1. I receive namespace collisions.
2. Fatal error when I try to `import Network` inside `Service` because there is no `Network` target after `pod install`. So I can't use one that framework with Swift Package Manager. CocoaPods just merges everything to one target `MyFramework` as I mentioned before.

#### Separate repos/pods

It's the solution but it's very hard to maintain multiple separate git repositories and make separate commit and pushes. I want to keep everything in a one repo.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to bundle them separately? So, you could have a Pod for Network and then you would declare a separate Service Pod, which itself would use Network as a Pod? :)

Comment: @Vasily did you found any solution ? I am also facing similar situation

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that CocoaPods doesn't have the ability to create separate targets for one podspec.

As you mention above you can create separate podspecs, but in one repository like [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift). Then while you are developing you can use some Example project which includes all your podspecs. You don't need to manage different repositories.

Also, you can try to create a module map with different modules, e.g.:

```
framework module Something {
    framework module Core { ... }
    framework module Toolbox { ... }
    ...
}
```

And then assign it in podspec, e.g.:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.module_map = "#{s.name}/#{s.name}.modulemap"
...
```

But I'm not sure about that. I've tried only the first way as in `RxSwift` repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below approach in the pod file, to specify different pods for each target.
You can also create multiple `def` and add different pods in each one in which can be used separately.

In the provided example I have 2 shared pods and 2 targets

- `target1_name` is the of one target
- `target2_name` is the name of another target
- `shared_pods` list of pods
- `shared_pods_2` list of another pods

  ```
  use_frameworks!    

  def shared_pods
   # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

   pod 'RealmSwift'
   pod 'Alamofire'
   pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
   pod 'SDWebImage'       
  end

  def shared_pods_2
   pod 'Fabric'
   pod 'Crashlytics'
   pod 'CryptoSwift'
  end

  target 'target1_name' do
   shared_pods
  end

  target 'target2_name' do
   shared_pods_2
  end
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is a Podfile, for using pods, whereas the question is about a podspec, for creating a pod